# Redirect dynamic domain from www to non-www

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server what have a lot of domains(more than a thousand) doing forward to it. 
What i need is handle all these forwards, redirecting any "https://www.any-domain" request to "https://any-domain".

Comment: You'd probably need separate configuration for each anyway, because they need own certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I created a separated server block to handle the `www`.